# How to emit event from child to parent? vuejs3

Tags: parameter-passing, vuejs3, eventemitter

Hello I have emitted method from child component(`Pagination.vue`) to parent(`Home.vue`).

Pagination is working like it is supposed to but I get `vue warn` and `error`.

**[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of native event handler .**

And I get this error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startsWith')**
I didn't create `startsWith`

Here is the code:

`Pagination.vue` component

```
 <div class="pagination">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary paginate-prev" @click="$emit(handleFilters({prevPage: currentPage}))">Prev</button>
      <div class="links">
        <span 
          v-for="link in links" 
          :key="link.id" 
          >
          <a :class="link.active ? 'active' : '' " href="#" @click="$emit(handleFilters({showPage: link.label}))">{{link.label}}</a></span>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-secondary paginate-next" @click="$emit(handleFilters({nextPage: currentPage}))">Next</button>
    </div>
export default {
      props: {
        links: Object,
        currentPage: Number
      },
      methods: {
        handleFilters(payload){
    
          this.$emit('handle-filters', payload)
        }
      }
    }
```

Home.vue parent

```
<pagination :currentPage="currentPage" :links="links" @handle-filters="handleFilters"/>
```

If you need something more tell me.
Again everything is working but I want to remove error and warning.

Comment: For Vue v3 you need an [emits](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/emits-option.html) option in your child component. And in your click handler you should remove the `$emit` statement - just call your `handleFilters` method, it will emit the event itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it.

Instaed of `@click="$emit(handleFilters({nextPage: currentPage}))"`

I wrote `@click="handleFilters({nextPage: currentPage})"`

I tried the new way but I get a lot of errors and I can't make it work.